# rjs - ruby loop inside page.alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have the following code in my rjs file:

```
if @books_by_author.count != 0
page.alert("The following books reference the author you want to delete: \n

     # here i want to list all the books referencing the author
");

end
```

How do I loop through @books_by_author and display their name inside the page.alert?

Thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.join`:

```
page.alert("The following books reference the author you want to delete: \n
            #{@books_by_author.join(', /n')} ");
```

Ultimation's suggession: if the array contains models, not strings, you need to map them to the title:

```
page.alert("The following books reference the author you want to delete: \n
            #{@books_by_author.map(&:title).join(', /n')} ");
```

Comment: or if they're objects i was going to suggest doing: @books_by_author.collect{|x| x.title}.join("\n")